# Why doesn't Chrome render this page correctly?

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with this page in Chrome:
http://www.pieterdedecker.be/index.htm

For those of you that don't have Chrome, here's what happens:
[Chrome screenshot http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/241/chromeerr.jpg](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/241/chromeerr.jpg)

How can I fix this glitch?

Comment: throw in some code rather than pic

Comment: and pic is helpful of course but show some code too

Comment: I don't want to be nasty, but putting text in a picture without providing a textual fallback (i.e. alt-tags or hidden text using text-indent:-9999px) is a very bad practice, considering accessibility.

Comment: Moreover, the same problem appears in IE7. In IE6, it renders very problematic. And though I also hate IE, I think giving an alert box even to users of IE7 that there browser is outdated is hostile to me. There are many IE users that simply cannot update there browser, for instance at work (and I know a lot of companies that still use IE6).

Comment: And lastly, I really don't want to be rude (I don't want to condemn you, I only want you to learn something about best practices), but claiming that you adhere to web standards (which goes further than creating valid HTML-pages) while providing such a poor accessibility level (just try Fangs to see what screen readers 'see') and using tables to layout your page is a kind of joke to me.

Comment: And to give you some advice: you can read more about adhering to standards and providing accessibility at the site of the Dutch government http://webrichtlijnen.nl (also in English, but I assume you can read Dutch as a Belgian).

Comment: @Marcel: how can I implement the text-indent fix without altering the page as it is shown to regular visitors?

Comment: It's described at http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/ (technique #3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative that will render correctly, and be a lot less code to maintain:

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
    color: #3D566E;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#top {
    background: url('img/wrap_top.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 300px;
}
#bodywrap {
    padding: 10px 20px 0 30px;
  background: url('img/wrap_body.png');
}
#bottom {
    padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px;
    background: url('img/wrap_bottom.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
}

table.grid {
    width: 100%;
}
/* Grid thumbnails */
table.grid a:link img, table.grid a:visited img, table.grid a:active img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #bbbbbb;
}
table.grid a:hover img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid #0075b5;
}
/* Exception for grid descriptor: see below */
table.grid tr td {
    text-align: center;
}
/* Grid descriptor */
table.grid tr td.grid_descriptor {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
table.grid tr td.grid_descriptor h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
table.grid tr td.grid_descriptor p {
    color: black;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
span.language {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

Here's the body replacement before the first body `<script>` tag:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bodywrap">
    <table class="grid">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td><a href="http://www.cybernetnews.com/author/pdedecker/"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/cybernetnews.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription(&#39;CyberNet News&#39;, &#39;Experiencing Facebook overkill? Looking for a one-click solution to make your photos look better?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;In my occassional contributions to CyberNet News, I show you how to make your digital life easier and more fun.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;EN\x3C/span&gt;&#39;);" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="CyberNet News" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/beradio/"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/beradio.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription(&#39;beRadio&#39;, &#39;This piece of software bundles popular Belgian radio stations in one app.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Added bonus: song information for most stations.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;\x3Ci&gt;Software, built with C#\x3C/i&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;EN\x3C/span&gt;&nbsp;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;NL\x3C/span&gt;&#39;);" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="beRadio" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/dvbt/"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/dvbt.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription(&#39;The Belgian DVB-T Resource&#39;, &#39;The missing manual to receiving free over-the-air television in Belgium.\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Ci&gt;Website, built with HTML/JS/CSS\x3C/i&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;EN\x3C/span&gt;&#39;);" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="The Belgian DVB-T Resource" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/ipodcalsync/"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/ipodcalsync.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription(&#39;iPodCALsync&#39;, &#39;A tool that lets iPod owners sync their Google calendars with their device.\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Ci&gt;Software, built with AutoItScript\x3Cbr /&gt;Not for the iPhone/iPod touch\x3C/i&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;EN\x3C/span&gt;&#39;);" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="iPodCALsync" /></a></td>
        <td class="grid_descriptor" rowspan="2" style="width: 30%">
          <h1 id="descriptor_title">Pick a thumbnail</h1>
          <p id="descriptor_body">Hover over a thumbnail to find out more about my projects.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/blog/"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/softwarelabo.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription(&#39;Pieter\&#39;s Software Lab&#39;, &#39;See what I\&#39;ve been cooking up in the labs. Has sneak peaks on new software and sites I may or may not release later.\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;NL\x3C/span&gt;&#39;);" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="Pieter&#39;s Software Lab" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.twitter.com/pdedecker"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/twitter.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription(&#39;My Twitter&#39;, &#39;My latest thoughts on tech, the world and bubble wrap.\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;EN\x3C/span&gt;&#39;);" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="My Twitter" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/podcast/itsallmellow/"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/itsallmellow.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription(&#39;It\&#39;s All Mellow&#39;, &#39;A podcast that features cheery and moody music to warm up your inner self.\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cbr /&gt;\x3Cspan class=\&#39;language\&#39;&gt;EN\x3C/span&gt;&#39;);" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="It&#39;s All Mellow" /></a></td>
        <td><a href="javascript:;"><img src="./Pieter De Decker's website_files/empty.png" alt="Coming soon?" /></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>  
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    Fascinated by the cat? You can find its owner <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/afu007/2398217277/" target="_blank">here</a>. An up-to-date browser such as <a href="http://www.getfirefox.com/" target="_blank">Firefox 3.5</a> or <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/netherlands/windows/internet-explorer/" target="_blank">Internet Explorer 8</a> ensures the site is rendered correctly. We're <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" target="_blank">compliant</a> with international web standards.
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a rather big change to fix your issue, but just showing you the option of a lot less HTML/CSS, but still XHTML compliant.  This is wiki, anyone else feel free to improve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running into an [empty cell glitch in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26293), I haven't tested it on your page but I've seen this same problem before on my sites. Try putting   or a single pixel image in your TD.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug where the background is being inherited by the table cells ...

You will have to not use the background image on the `tr` but on the `td` instead..

so your following code

```
<tr class="body"> 
    <td class="spacer"></td> 
    <td class="content">....</td> 
    <td class="spacer"></td> 
</tr>
```

will have to change to

```
<tr class="body"> 
    <td class="spacer left"></td> 
    <td class="content center">....</td> 
    <td class="spacer right"></td> 
</tr>
```

and in your CSS add

```
table.wrapper .body td{ 
    background-image: url('img/wrap_body.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-y; 
}
table.wrapper .body td.left{ background-position: 0 0; }
table.wrapper .body td.center{ background-position: 50% 0; }
table.wrapper .body td.right{ background-position: 100% 0; }
```

and change

```
table.wrapper tr.body, table.wrapper tr.bodyspacer {
    background: url('img/wrap_body.png');
}
```

to

```
table.wrapper tr.bodyspacer {
    background: url('img/wrap_body.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your:

```
table.wrapper td.spacer
```

Looks like the width isn't rendering correctly. It is also not rendering in IE8 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `background-repeat: no-repeat;` declaration to your `table.wrapper tr.body` rule-set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the td's inheriting the background of the parent tr. This is more noticeable if you turn off the background color here:

```
table.wrapper td.content {
    vertical-align: top;
    /*background-color: #EEEEEE;*/
}
```

To minimize necessary changes to your table layout, you could just move your spacers to the "grid" table and remove the colspan=3 declaration from the cells in the other rows:

```
<tr class="body"> 
    <!--td class="spacer"> </td--> 
    <td class="content"> 
        <table class="grid"> 
            <tr> 
                <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.cybernetnews.com/author/pdedecker/"><img src="img/thumbs/cybernetnews.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription('CyberNet News', 'Experiencing Facebook overkill? Looking for a one-click solution to make your photos look better?<br /><br />In my occassional contributions to CyberNet News, I show you how to make your digital life easier and more fun.<br /><br />\x3Cspan class=\'language\'>EN\x3C/span>');" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="CyberNet News" /></a></td> 
                <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/beradio/"><img src="img/thumbs/beradio.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription('beRadio', 'This piece of software bundles popular Belgian radio stations in one app.<br /><br />Added bonus: song information for most stations.<br /><br />\x3Ci>Software, built with C#\x3C/i>\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Cspan class=\'language\'>EN\x3C/span> \x3Cspan class=\'language\'>NL\x3C/span>');" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="beRadio" /></a></td> 
                <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/dvbt/"><img src="img/thumbs/dvbt.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription('The Belgian DVB-T Resource', 'The missing manual to receiving free over-the-air television in Belgium.\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Ci>Website, built with HTML/JS/CSS\x3C/i>\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Cspan class=\'language\'>EN\x3C/span>');" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="The Belgian DVB-T Resource" /></a></td> 
                <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/ipodcalsync/"><img src="img/thumbs/ipodcalsync.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription('iPodCALsync', 'A tool that lets iPod owners sync their Google calendars with their device.\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Ci>Software, built with AutoItScript\x3Cbr />Not for the iPhone/iPod touch\x3C/i>\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Cspan class=\'language\'>EN\x3C/span>');" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="iPodCALsync" /></a></td> 
                <td class="grid_descriptor" rowspan="2" style="width: 30%"><h1 id="descriptor_title"></h1><p id="descriptor_body"></p></td> 
                <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr> 
                <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
                <td><a href="http://labs.pieterdedecker.be/blog/"><img src="img/thumbs/softwarelabo.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription('Pieter\'s Software Lab', 'See what I\'ve been cooking up in the labs. Has sneak peaks on new software and sites I may or may not release later.\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Cspan class=\'language\'>NL\x3C/span>');" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="Pieter's Software Lab" /></a></td> 
                <td><a href="http://www.twitter.com/pdedecker"><img src="img/thumbs/twitter.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription('My Twitter', 'My latest thoughts on tech, the world and bubble wrap.\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Cspan class=\'language\'>EN\x3C/span>');" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="My Twitter" /></a></td> 
                <td><a href="http://www.pieterdedecker.be/podcast/itsallmellow/"><img src="img/thumbs/itsallmellow.jpg" onmouseover="showDescription('It\'s All Mellow', 'A podcast that features cheery and moody music to warm up your inner self.\x3Cbr />\x3Cbr />\x3Cspan class=\'language\'>EN\x3C/span>');" onmouseout="revertDescription();" alt="It's All Mellow" /></a></td> 
                <td><a href="javascript:;"><img src="img/thumbs/empty.png" alt="Coming soon?" /></a></td> 
                <td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </td> 
    <!--td class="spacer"> </td--> 
</tr>;
```